# Select row only whent tapped on checkbox not on the row itself

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can't get that behaviour - row must become selected only by tapping on default checkbox in UITableView edit mode with multiple selection allowed.
When tapped on row elsewhere  - row did not become selected but another details screen will open.

WORKOROUND (Xamarin C#):

```
    // MyTableCell : UITableViewCell

    public bool IsCheckBoxTapped;

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        var touch = touches.FirstOrDefault() as UITouch;
        var point = touch?.LocationInView(this) ?? new CGPoint();

        var r = CGRect.FromLTRB(0, 0, 60, Frame.Height);
        IsCheckBoxTapped = r.Contains(point);

        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is that you override the touches began method in a custom cell class in such a way that if the user touches the cell in the area that holds the checkbox, it will do something different than if they touch the area that does not hold the checkbox. Something similar to what I have below might work.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var point:CGPoint = CGPoint()

    if let touch = touches.first {
        point = touch.locationInView(self)
    }

    if(checkBox.frame.contains(point)) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        //or however you would like to select the row
    }
    else {
        //present your details screen
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get reference to checkBox view?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? You can create an outlet connection from the storyboard to your class

Comment: In storyboard i define custom cell class but checkbox is not presented in layout, so i can not create outlet - i'm using API internal Checkbox that appears automatically when user enters in TableView's edit mode.

Comment: I wouldn't know how you'd get a reference to that checkbox then. Alternatively you could calculate the coordinates of the checkbox and make a frame

Comment: I made new Rect with coords from the beginning of Table cell and with reasonable width that wraps that checkbox and then use your approach with touchesBegan func. That's kind of workaround so i mark answer as accepted till better solution comes up for dynamic multiple screen sizes, tnx.